# onelogin: why is RequestedAuthnContext required?

Tags: onelogin

Take [AuthNRequest sample](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_req.php)

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="ONELOGIN_809707f0030a5d00620c9d9df97f627afe9dcc24" Version="2.0" ProviderName="SP test" IssueInstant="2014-07-16T23:52:45Z" Destination="http://idp.example.com/SSOService.php" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://sp.example.com/demo1/index.php?acs">
  <saml:Issuer>http://sp.example.com/demo1/metadata.php</saml:Issuer>
  <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" AllowCreate="true"/>
  <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
    <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
  </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

put it into [Validate XML with the XSD schema](https://www.samltool.com/validate_xml.php) and choose
**AuthNRequest** for **XSD (schema file)**.

That validates fine.  Now take out the RequestedAuthnContext element, validation will fail with:
**Invalid XSD for this XML**.

Googling for **urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol** I find multiple instances
of saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd [including this one](https://gist.github.com/alim/651bc358e57498f06756).

Question 1)

Do I get **Invalid XSD for this XML** because:

```
<element name="RequestedAuthnContext" type="samlp:RequestedAuthnContextType"/>
```

doesn't have:

```
minOccurs="0"
```

?

Question 2)

Looking at section **3.4.1 Element**  of [saml-core-2.0-os.pdf](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf), it says:

```
<RequestedAuthnContext> [Optional]
```

Is the .xsd wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That validation tool uses internally php-saml and the xsd used to validate the XML: https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/blob/master/lib/Saml2/schemas/saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd#L114

You can see it uses:

And lacks the minOccurs

And you are right..it seems is wrong since a valid AuthNRequest can omit that element.

Reference: http://www.datypic.com/sc/saml2/e-samlp_AuthnRequest.html

I will fix it